# Knowing how to wield regular expressions unleashes processing powers you might not even know were available

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Knowing how to wield regular expressions unleashes **processing powers you might not even know were available.**

What does it mean?

- to me, it is "you might not even know the fact that processing powers were available."
- but, it is like "the processing powers (which you might not even know) were available"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it means the first of those two interpretations. We can exclude the second interpretation by substituting "unknown" for "which you might not even know". That would leave

> Knowing how to wield regular expressions unleashes unknown processing powers were available.

That is clearly not grammatical, because "were available" has to connect to "know" in the relative clause. So, it's not the powers that were unknown, but the availability.

Comment: Can you explain more on relative clause? Is it “Knowing how to wield regular expressions unleashes processing powers you might not even know (which) were available"?

Comment: The original has a reduced form of "Knowing how to wield regular expressions,unleashes powers [which] you might not even know were available." Omitting the  relative pronoun "which" makes it a reduced clause, but doesn't change the meaning. You migtht like to check out https://www.thoughtco.com/relative-clause-grammar-1692042  and numerous other references on the net.